# How can I pass input (event) parameters through API Gateway into Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I understand that API Gateway (AG) passes params into Lambda as JSON payload.

I have setup a POST API with Lambda Proxy in AG. My lambda function takes the following param list :

```
{
  "fullname": "Mr xxxxx",
  "clientemail": "xxxxxx@xxx.com",
  "clientphone": "0800 088 8888",
  "locationtext": "Laxxxxxx Hotel , CA, USA",
  "subject": "Gxxxxxrth",
  "appointmentblock_min": "60",
  "buffer": "120",
  "calendar_id": "xxxxx",
  "thedate": "2021-03-2xxxxxx",
  "thetime": "xxxxx"
}
```

Testing directly within the Lambda console. Everything works fine.  I map all parameters in the code using the lambda EVENT object as follows :

```
fullname = event['fullname']  
clientemail = event['clientemail']
appointmentblock_min = int(event['appointmentblock_min'])
```

... and so on.

All code works fine.

Adding the API Gateway component on top ... and things don't work.

The specific problem : how can I map the lambda input parameters coming from API Gateway (AG) to lambda ?
I realise that AG is sending JSON into Lambda. How to parse this payload to extract and use the parameters that I need.

I have tried to create a dict containing all the parameters :

```
Event = {}
Event = json.loads(body)
Event = json.loads(event.body)
```

No docs explicitly explain how to grab the event object params via AG.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS I am expecting to return data back to AG as follows :

```
return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            'body': json.dumps(out_message),
            'isBase64Encoded': 'false'
        }
```

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: AG Error : Tue Mar 23 19:49:32 UTC 2021 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'thedate'. Lambda request id: 328e-4263-9237-174dce236e44
Tue Mar 23 19:49:32 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 502 

thedate refers to  Lambda code . Assign the variable 'thedate' to  input param :

thedate = event['thedate']

Answer (score 2):

According to TestEvents in Lambda, the input you get on Lambda will be

[LambdaTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fdAO.png)

So you can load your payload (or body) as

```
Event = json.loads(event['body'])
```